# Fixing row height for different row divs boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Apologies, my HTML bootstrap knowledge is limited and though I tried different approaches it did not help solve the problem.

**What I expect:**

**Div Row 1** -> 10% of the max height

**Div Row 2** -> 70% of the max height

**Div Row 3** -> remaining 20% of the max height

Also, I expect the entire container to fit within the viewable area i.e. **no scrolling** and **responsive** to the screen size. I am unable to achieve that...Thank you in advance!

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <audio id="mySong" src=""></audio>
  <div class="row row1">Counter: <span id="iteration"></span></div>
  <div class="row row2">
    <video class="input_video col-md-6 hidden"></video>
    <div class = "embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 col-md-6">
      <video id="videosToPlay" width="100%" autoplay playsinline>
        <source id="idle_video" src="" type="video/mp4">
      </video>  
    </div>
    <canvas class="output_canvas col-md-6" width="640px" height="480px"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="row top-buffer row3">
    <canvas class="bar_canvas col-md-12"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
.hidden { visibility:hidden; display:none; }

html, body, .container-fluid {
    height:100%;
}

.top-buffer { margin-top:20px; }

.row1  {
    height:10%;
} 


.row2  {
    height:70%;
} 

.row3  {
    height:20%;
}
```

Comment: Could you add your CSS to the question?

Comment: @BorisNL I just added it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use vh instead of %. using 100vh will take the 100% of the screen height.

```
html, body, .container-fluid {
    height:100vh;
}

.top-buffer { margin-top:20px; }

.row1  {
    height:10vh;
} 


.row2  {
    height:70vh;
} 

.row3  {
    height:20vh;
}
```

Comment: Hi. this works, but I need the scroll bar to go. Everything should fit within the screen.

Comment: your <canvas> has a definite height 480px. now if the whole things has height higher than your screen height it will overflow (scroll bar will be showing)

Answer (score 0):

Try using view-height in stead of percentages, and give the body no padding and no margin:

```css
html,
body,
.container-fluid {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.top-buffer { margin-top:20px; }

.row1  {
    height: 10vh;
} 

.row2  {
    height: 70vh;
} 

.row3  {
    height: 20vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! the view-height helped, but still, there is a scrollbar. I do not need any scrolling.

Comment: If you don't need any scrolling at all, you can use overflow: hidden; to hide all scroll bars.

Comment: I did use that, but then the content on the canvas i.e. the last div overflows outside the view and I can only see it partially. So, overflow: hidden; isn't sufficient.